# Writing an itoa function

Tags: c

Here is a basic itoa function that I've written trying to use recursion:

```
void itoa(int number, char buffer[])
{
    static int idx=0, size=0;
    if (number == 0) {
        buffer[size] = '\0';
        idx = size = 0; // reset for next call
    }
    else {
        size++, idx++;
        itoa(number/10, buffer);
        buffer[size-idx--] = (number % 10) + '0';
    }
}
```

How does it look? It is not thread-safe due to the static, but is that an issue for a function such as this? If so, how could I update that? What other ways could I make improvements to it?

Comment: _How does it look?_ - scary. Besides, if `number` is 0 to begin with, it doesn't give the correct result.

Comment: Why did you want a recursive function?  That's usually a poor choice in C if there's a simple iterative version possible.

Comment: How do you know the buffer is big enough? The recursion doesn't seem to place things in the right place... Couldn't you just use `sprintf`?

Comment: @MrR 1. It's up to caller to provide the buffer long enough. 3. I suppose the `printf` functions family utilizes the same routine for `int` arguments as `itoa()` does, so redirecting `itoa` to `sprintf` may be a kind of an infinite loop....

Comment: @CiaPan this is the OP own function not the builtin - so should be okay.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to care about negative values of `number`...

Comment: @TobySpeight I see. out of curiosity, why would recursion be different in C than any other language though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does it look?

Not so good.

1. Not thread safe.
2. Does not handle negative numbers well.
3. Forms `""` with 0.
4. Prone to buffer overflow.
5. `itoa()` is not a standard function, yet it commonly returns a pointer.

A test harness

```
int main(void) {
  char buf[100];
  int test[] = {123, 456, 0, - 42, INT_MAX, INT_MIN};
  int n = sizeof test / sizeof *test;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    itoa(test[i], buf);
    printf("%-11d <%s>\n", test[i], buf);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
123         <123>
456         <456>
0           <>
-42         <,.>
2147483647  <2147483647>
-2147483648 <./,),(-*,(>
```

---

> It is not thread-safe due to the static, but is that an issue for a function such as this?

Yes.  Thread safety is expected.

---

> If so, how could I update that? What other ways could I make improvements to it?

I really do not think this is a good place to use recursion given the potential for buffer overflow is a fair complication.

But if one *must* use recursion, consider adding error checking and test for various sorts of `int` including `0, INT_MAX, INT_MIN`.

```
static char* itoa_helper(int number, size_t sz, char buffer[]) {
  if (sz == 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  if (number <= -10) {
    buffer = itoa_helper(number / 10, sz - 1, buffer);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
      return NULL;
    }
    number %= 10;
  }
  *buffer = (char) ('0' - number);
  return buffer + 1;
}

char* itoa_recursive_alt(int number, size_t sz, char buffer[sz]) {
  if (sz == 0 || buffer == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  char *s = buffer;

  if (number >= 0) {
    // Flip pos numbers to neg as neg range is greater.
    number = -number;
  } else {
    sz--;
    if (sz == 0) {
      *buffer = '\0';
      return NULL;
    }
    *s++ = '-';
  }
  s = itoa_helper(number, sz-1, s);
  if (s == NULL) {
    *buffer = '\0';
    return NULL;
  }
  *s = 0;
  return buffer;
}

int main(void) {
  char buf[100];
  int test[] = {123, 456, 0, -42, INT_MAX, INT_MIN};
  int n = sizeof test / sizeof *test;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // char *s = itoa_recursive_alt(test[i], sizeof buf, buf);
    char *s = itoa_recursive_alt(test[i], sizeof buf, buf);
    if (s == NULL)
      s = "NULL";
    printf("%-11d <%s> <%s>\n", test[i], s, buf);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
123         <123> <123>
456         <456> <456>
0           <0> <0>
-42         <-42> <-42>
2147483647  <2147483647> <2147483647>
-2147483648 <-2147483648> <-2147483648>
```

Comment: awesome, thank you so much for putting in the time. A few questions: (1) what's the downside of not doing the covert-to-negative? (2) what's the downside of not passing a `size` to the itoa function? Can't the callee determine the size and just set a max-length and return an error if there's truncation?

Comment: @carl.hiass 1) what's the downside of not doing the covert-to-negative? --> Explain how you are going to handle `INT_MIN` which is less than `-INT_MAX`.  2)  what's the downside of not passing a size to the itoa function? --> Risking buffer overflow 3)   Can't the callee determine the size and just set a max-length and return an error if there's truncation? --->Unless the caller provides a _size_, the callee does not know how much is too much.  The callee does not control the amount of buffer that can be used.  The caller knows though.

Comment: @carl.hiass Was _recursion_ a requirement?

Comment: no I was just learning about it and trying out with that. I thought it might get rid of the need to reverse (which it does) but obviously there are a lot of other issues it introduces.

Comment: I've written an updated version based on your help -- thanks again! https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/257428/improving-an-itoa-function